# run Spring boot service after database in docker swarm

Tags: java, docker, docker-swarm

I'm using docker swarm. I have two services.

1. Spring boot app
2. PostgreSQL database

every things is ok. suppose :
all of my tasks be kill for any reason (for example restart the server) swarm try to run my services.
my problem is there if first run spring boot then run database. in this status my spring boot can not connect to database. and my app not working.
I know that I can resolve this problem in spring with connection pool but I want handle it in docker swarm.
can you help me?
is there any way ????

Comment: In which way are you configuring swarm containers? Docker compose?

Comment: I manually create services. but if is necessary to use docker-compose, I use it

Comment: For compose deployment there is an answer which can be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y

Comment: thanks. but I want to use docker swarm